# "Cutting" id output

Tags: awk, cut

I need to write a script that would "cut" the output of the id command into three parts. For example:

Let's say id gives this output: `uid=12345(mylogin) gid=100(users)`

And my script should  output it like this:

```
Login: mylogin
Id: 12345
Group: users
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using multiple character field separator in `awk`

```
$ echo 'uid=12345(mylogin) gid=100(users)' | awk -F'[=()]' '{print "Login: " $3 "\nId: " $2 "\nGroup: " $6}'
Login: mylogin
Id: 12345
Group: users
```

- `-F'[=()]'` set `=` or `(` or `)` as field separators
- `$3` will be third field, after first `=` and the first `(` terminated by `)`. So it gets the value `mylogin`
- Similarly for other fields and print as required

Comment: Thank you. This task was placed under "awk" command paragraph in my learning material so I will accept this answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 17):

Don't bother trying to parse it.  POSIX [requires](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/id.html) that `id` support various options to do this automatically:

```
printf "Login: %s\nId: %s\nGroup: %s\n" "$(id -un)" "$(id -u)" "$(id -gn)"
```

In addition to being more work, parsing is complicated by the fact that `id` with no options is permitted to produce locale-dependent output:

> The following formats shall be used when the LC_MESSAGES locale category specifies the POSIX locale. **In other locales, the strings uid, gid, euid, egid, and groups may be replaced with more appropriate strings corresponding to the locale.**

While most reasonable parsing tools can cope with this, anything that isn't Unicode-aware may have problems.

Answer (score 8):

One way can be:

```
# 0 |  1  |   2   |  3 | 4 |  5  |
#uid=12345(mylogin) gid=100(users)
IFS='(=)' read -a A <<<"$(id)"
printf '%s: %s\n' Login "${A[2]}" Id "${A[1]}" Group "${A[5]}"
# remember array A indexing begins at 0.
```

Answer (score 4):

Literally, using only `cut`:

```
echo Login: $(id | cut -d ' ' -f1 | cut -d= -f2 | cut -d '(' -f1)
echo Id: $(id | cut -d ' ' -f1 | cut -d= -f2 | cut -d '(' -f2 | cut -d  ')' -f1)
echo Group: $(id | cut -d ' ' -f2 | cut -d '(' -f2 | cut -d ')' -f1)
```